# Vim - autocmd not working for C++ file type

Tags: vim, autocmd

I'm using Windows with Vim 7.4. In my `_vimrc` file I have

```
set ts=4 sw=4 sts=4
augroup Foo
    au!
    au BufRead,BufNewFile *.xml,*.css setlocal ts=2 sw=2 sts=2
    au BufRead,BufNewFile *.h,*.cc setlocal ts=2 sw=2 sts=2
augroup END
```

When I open `myFile.h` or `myFile.cc`, TAB is set to 4 spaces not 2 spaces, but when I open `MyFile.css`, TAB is set to 2 spaces. It seems that for *.cc and *.h file, my `autocmd` not getting executed. Does anyone knows why and how can I fix this? (I want my TAB to be set to 4 spaces for *.cpp and *.hpp files and all other files except *.xml, *.css, *.h and *.cc).

Comment: Try `:verbose set sw?` to find out, if it is set from your _vimrc or some other file (like _gvimrc or some plugin). Or you can try to [keep your _vimrc file clean](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_your_vimrc_file_clean).

Answer (score 0):

You can just put them on one line.

```
set ts=4 sw=4 sts=4
augroup Foo
    au!
    au BufEnter,BufNewFile *.xml,*.css,*.h,*.cc setlocal ts=2 sw=2 sts=2
augroup END
```